# How can I set the DateTime of a comment created programmatically in PowerPoint?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, add-in

I'm coding an add-in for PowerPoint 2010 and I have to create programmatically differents comments which must appear in a lot of slides. 
The way to add a comment is the code below :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides[index].comments.Add(posX,posY,"author","authorInitials","comment");
```

The problem with that is the DateTime is automatically set to the DateTime.Now and the setter is private. I want to set manually the dateTime property but I don't find the way to do this.

How can I set the DateTime of a comment created programmatically in PowerPoint?

Comment: Are you adding the date/time to every slide???  Can you just add it to the slide master?  Granted, you have the same issue there in that if you specify date/time, you'll get the current date/time, but you don't have to modify every single slide in the presentation.

Comment: Actually, each comment may have a different date of creation

Answer (score 1):

Add it as a part of the comment, instead of using the date/time tag.  Of couse, this means that the date/time displayed will not be reformatted to the localization of the current user, but that may not be important to you.

Comment: I also thought to this solution (directly write the date in the comment) but it's not the solution that I hopped.
Is it easy to hide the datetime automatically created by PowerPoint in the comment?

Comment: Use of date/time field is up to the user.  It is possible for the user to specify their own on the slide master and thwart your scheme, however, you may be able to programmatically hide it.  Either way, it might be confusing for your user unless you provide some sort of indication as to what your code is doing, in the form of a message.

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime property of Comments is read-only.

You might possibly save the current time, set the computer's clock to the time you want to appear on the comments, then reset the computer's clock afterward (allowing for the amount of time elapsed in the interim).